# i am getting a error in open

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form4
    Dim objcon As New OleDbConnection
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strconnection As String = "provider=microsoft.ACE.OLEDO.12.0;Data Source=shweta:\WindowsApplication1\Databaseapp.accdb"
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim attempt As Integer = 0

    Private Sub btnsignin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsignin.Click
        Dim strName = txtpassword.Text
        Dim strpass = txtpassword.Text
        With objcon
            .Close()
            If .State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                .ConnectionString = strconnection
                .Open()
                '{they r showing An unhandled exception of type 
                'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in 
                ' System.Data.dll  }}
                MsgBox("connectionstate.open", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "connected")


            End If
        End With
        ds.Clear()
        strSQL = "Select * from logintable where username='" & Txtusername.Text & "' And password =''" & txtpassword.Text '"
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, objcon)
        da.Fill(ds, "logintable")
        If ds.Tables("logintable").Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            MaximizeBox = True
            MinimizeBox = True
        Else
            MaximizeBox = False
            MinimizeBox = False
            MessageBox.Show("invalid")

        End If
        Form2.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: First provide proper ConnectionString, even a single char can spoil it, **Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0**. Also verify your data source path **shweta:\WindowsApplication1\...**. More about connection strings: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Answer (score -2):

Here are errors fixed:

1. It works if could put `Imports System.Data.OleDb` before `Public Class Form4`.
2. Also, add `Public Property Form2 As Object` inside form4 block.

Still some part of code is missing. Could you please specify them?

Comment: None of those are any fixes to his problem! It doesn't matter if you import `OleDb` or not, and declaring an object called `Form2` will create more problems than what he first had.